# Initial value of a flip flop on logisim

Tags: flip-flop

I am implementing flipflops in logisim. Usually, their output gets back to the circuit as their own inputs. This only works if I manually insert an initial value to the flipflop and then reconnect its output to the input - otherwise, Logisim mark the connection in red and I get no output value.

Is there an easy way to set up the initial value of a flip flop in Logisim, so that I avoid having to break the connection all the time, adding an input and then reconnecting output and input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was using a D-flip flop designed manually. Using logisim built-in flipflops works perfectly.